# Delphi authentication of Drupal 7 passwords

Tags: php, delphi, drupal, sha512

I am trying to authenticate Drupal 7 passwords with Delphi 10.

I am mimicking the `_password_crypt()` function which uses the PHP `hash( ,,TRUE)` function.

The hashing process is repeated and starts with a string and switched to bytes;

```
  $hash = hash($algo, $salt . $password, TRUE);
  do {
    $hash = hash($algo, $hash . $password, TRUE);
  } while (--$count);
  $len = strlen($hash);
  $output = $setting . _password_base64_encode($hash, $len);
```

Can this be replicated with `THashSHA2`? If so, can you outline the approach?

Comment: After 11 years you should have learned that a **full** example would help more: how are `$algo`, `$salt`, `$password` and `$setting` defined and which value does `$output` then contain? Because with that input and output data translated code can be checked for working the same way (instead of just assuming). What have you attempted so far? Which parts are a problem for you?

Comment: There is all in the documentation https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!password.inc/function/_password_crypt/7.x

Answer (score 0):

```
unit DrupalPasseordClass;

interface

uses System.SysUtils, System.Classes, System.Hash;

const
  DRUPAL_HASH_LENGTH=55;

type
  TDrupalPassword=record

  private
    function _password_itoa64(): String;
    function CombineByteArrays(ABytes, BBytes: TBytes): TBytes;
    function _password_get_count_log2(setting: String): Integer;
    function _password_base64_encode(hash: TBytes; count: Integer): String;
  public
    function CheckPassword(Password, StoredHash: String): Boolean;

End;


implementation

function TDrupalPassword._password_itoa64(): String;
begin
  result:='./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
end;

function TDrupalPassword._password_get_count_log2(setting: String): Integer;
var
 itoa64: String;
begin
  itoa64:= _password_itoa64();
  result:=Pos(setting[4], itoa64)-1;
end;

function TDrupalPassword.CombineByteArrays(ABytes, BBytes: TBytes): TBytes;
var
  k: Integer;
begin
  result:=ABytes;
  SetLength(result, Length(ABytes)+Length(BBytes));
  for k := 0 to Length(BBytes)-1 do
    result[Length(ABytes)+k]:=BBytes[k];
end;

function TDrupalPassword.CheckPassword(Password, StoredHash: String): Boolean;
var
  Count, k: Integer;
  algorithm, ComputedHash, Salt, Setting: String;
  Hash: TBytes;
  bPassword, bSalt, bSeed: TBytes;
  BS: TBytesStream;
begin
  BS:=TBytesStream.Create;
  try
    algorithm:=Copy(StoredHash,1, 3);
    if not algorithm.Equals('$S$') then
       Exit(False);

    Setting:=Copy(StoredHash,1, 12);
    Salt:=Copy(StoredHash, 5, 8);

    bSalt:=TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sALT);
    bPassword:=TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Password);
    bSeed:=CombineByteArrays(bSalt, bPassword);

    BS.WriteData(bSeed, Length(bSeed));
    BS.Seek(0, soBeginning);
    Hash:=THashSHA2.GetHashBytes(BS, SHA512);

    Count:=1 ShL _password_get_count_log2(Setting);
    for k:=1 to Count do
    begin
      bSeed:=CombineByteArrays(Hash, bPassword);
      BS.Clear;
      BS.Write(bSeed, Length(bSeed));
      BS.Seek(0, soBeginning);
      Hash:=THashSHA2.GetHashBytes(BS, SHA512);
    end;
    ComputedHash:=Setting+_password_base64_encode(Hash, Length(Hash));
    ComputedHash:=Copy(ComputedHash,1,DRUPAL_HASH_LENGTH);
    result:=(StoredHash=ComputedHash);
  finally
    bs.Free;
  end;
end;

function TDrupalPassword._password_base64_encode(hash: TBytes; count: Integer): String;
var
  Index, Value: Integer;
  itoa64: String;
begin
  result:='';
  itoa64:= _password_itoa64();
  Index:=0;
  repeat
    value:=ord(hash[Index]);
    result:=result+itoa64[(value and $3f)+1];
    inc(Index);
    if (Index < count) then
      value:=value or  ord(Hash[Index]) shl 8;

    result:=result+itoa64[(value shr 6 and $3f)+1];
    if (Index >= count) then
      break;
    inc(Index);

    if (Index < count) then
      value:=value or ord(Hash[Index]) shl 16;

    result:=result+itoa64[(value shr 12 and $3f)+1];
    if (Index>= count) then
      break;
    inc(Index);
    result:=result+itoa64[(value shr 18 and $3f)+1];
  until (Index>count);
end;

end.
```